# Registering async factory in Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, async-await, c#-5.0

I have a Wallet class that I get from a repository. I'm trying to properly register both in Autofac so classes using the wallet could have a proper instance injected. The problem is that the repository uses an async method (returning Task). Does Autofac support such cases?

This doesn't work:

```
cb.RegisterType<WalletRepository>()
    .As<IWalletRepository>()
    .SingleInstance();
cb.Register(async c => await c.Resolve<IWalletRepository>().CreateAsync(App.WalletPath));
cb.RegisterType<ViewModel>()
    .AsSelf().
    .SingleInstance();
```

Somewhere in the app I just have:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(Wallet wallet)
    {
        //nothing fancy here
    }
}
```

When calling `container.Resolve<ViewModel>()` i get an exception saying Wallet is not registered.

Comment: Could you include the consuming code, or at least the ctor and example method using the injected dependency?

Comment: Not answering the question but I'd say your WalletRepository shouldn't need IO to be initialized in the first place. Try initializing it lazily on the first use of one of its methods.

Comment: It's not a repository initialized with IO but a Wallet object (they are loaded from files).

Comment: Why do you even have async initialization when you're then resolving the view model synchronously?

Comment: @Pein loading from a file *is* IO. Try loading lazily and those problems go away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken Autofac doesn't have any specific support for `async` factories. You can still make it work, but you have to write some boilerplate code, because constructor injection won't work. You also have to be more literal and say you want `Task<T>` instead of `T`. The whole code would look something like this:

```
cb.RegisterType<WalletRepository>()
  .As<IWalletRepository>()
  .SingleInstance();
cb.Register(c => c.Resolve<IWalletRepository>().CreateAsync(App.WalletPath));
cb.Register(async c => new ViewModel(await c.Resolve<Task<Wallet>>()))
  .SingleInstance();
var container = cb.Build();
var viewModel = await container.Resolve<Task<ViewModel>>();
```

It's possible Autofac has some extensibility points to make this code simpler, but I don't know enough about it to help you with that.

Comment: It looks like capturing "c" is prohibited: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/concurrency.html#service-resolution

Comment: @astef My code does not use `c` after the lambda is invoked and returns a `Task`, so I think it should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

This might cause a deadlock. Autofac is using locks in some of the logic that handles the resolving for different lifetime scopes. so if the the async factory operation will try to resolve something in another thread you will get a deadlock

Comment: was this meant to be a comment on another answer?

Answer (score 0):

One option is just to make the registration do the blocking required to convert the async call into it's result.

ie:

```
cb.Register(c => c.Resolve<IWalletRepository>().CreateAsync(App.WalletPath).Result); // nb: blocking call
```

This means that AutoFac will be forced to do the blocking when the dependencies are resolved, and the client of the service need not know that the service factory was async.

Whether this is a good idea will depend largely on what you are doing at the time of course.

Comment: `.Result` should be avoid because it wraps up exceptions.

use: `.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` instead.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835063/difference-between-getawaiter-and-configureawait

Comment: Valid code, but you should only do this if you're "forced" to by third party code you cannot modify. Object graph construction should follow simple-constructor semantics, and complete synchronously and quickly wherever possible. Blocking on asynchronous code [has it's own dangers](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) as well.