# Difference between .GetAwaiter() and ConfigureAwait()

Tags: c#, async-await

Can any one tell me difference between `GetAwaiter()` and `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Both of them are used in Async method to solve the deadlock situation and `ConfigureAwait` to complete task without using Synchrnoization context. I'm looking for scenarios where we can use `GetAwaiter()` and where we use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

I heard if it is library I'm building then I need to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` which generates Configurable Awaitable object of Await task. Can I use `ConfigureAwait` in Unittest case project or should use `GetAwaiter()` which get await task.

Comment: Your question is at the same time far too broad and not clear at all. The two methods do completely different things; what "difference" other than that do you think is worth asking about? Neither are used _"to solve the deadlock situation"_; it's true that correct use of either can _avoid_ deadlock, but it's not like you start with some random deadlock, throw in a call to one of those methods and, Bob's your uncle, deadlock is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Extracted from MSDN Docs

[Task.GetAwaiter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx)
Gets an awaiter used to await this task. See more details [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx).

[Task.ConfigureAwaiter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx)
Configures an awaiter used to await this task. See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Hi Nipuna, Can ContinueWith() resolves deadlock issue like .ContinueWith().GetAwaiter().getResult()

Answer (score 2):

Here is some guidance:

[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

and another similar question:

[Preventing a deadlock when calling an async method without using await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887915/preventing-a-deadlock-when-calling-an-async-method-without-using-await)

You can use [Rx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) to mimic async operations in unit tests. I would advise against having actual async in unit tests; it would slow them down and discourage using those unit tests.