# How to call async method in Autofac registration?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, autofac, factory

I want to do call an `awaitable async` method during a registration like this:

```
// builder variable contains Autofac ContainerBuilder
builder.Register(
    (async (context, parameters) => // need async here
        {
            var someClass = new SomeClass(context.Resolve<ISomeDependency>());
            await someClass.SomeAsyncInitMethod(); // need to await result
            return someClass;
        })).As<ISomeClass>().SingleInstance();
```

`SomeClass` implements `ISomeClass` as Service.
The important part is the `someClass.SomeAsyncInitMethod()` call. This is `async`, so because of this I need to `await` it here and put the `async` keyword into the `Register` method. But now `Autofac` thinks this returns a `Task<SomeClass>` which is not registerable as `Service` `ISomeClass`.

How to achieve the above and register `SomeClass` as `ISomeClass` when awaiting the `async` init Method?

Comment: looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854245/registering-async-factory-in-autofac

Comment: Similar question/issue filed: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/751

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that doing any I/O intensive work at resolution phase is wrong design, because it's usually important to have full control over the order of this operations, catch their exceptions, repeat them, control time between some of them, etc.

Solution is to postpone them with factories. Let me replace `SomeClass` with a more meaningful `NpgsqlConnection`:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(context =>
{
    // make sure not to capture temporary context:
    // https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/concurrency.html#service-resolution
    var connectionString = context.Resolve<IConfiguration>().GetConnectionString("MyDb");

    return new Func<Task<NpgsqlConnection>>(async () =>
    {
        var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        return connection;
    });
});
```

And here's how connection user can look like:

```
public sealed class Repository
{
    private readonly Func<Task<NpgsqlConnection>> _connectionFactory;

    public Repository(Func<Task<NpgsqlConnection>> connectionFactory)
    {
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetServerVersionAsync()
    {
        using (var openedConnection = await _connectionFactory())
            return openedConnection.ServerVersion;
    }
}
```

Even if Autofac would support async registrations, it is still would be beneficial to require a factory in `Repository` constructor, because the connection is a limited resource and it is better to limit the time it is opened.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but I think autofac does not support that.

We used:

```
builder.Register(c =>
  {
      var bar= c.Resolve<IBar>();
      var foo = new Foo(bar);
      return foo.ComputeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  })
.As<IFoo>()
.SingleInstance();
```

But as mentioned on the comments: [Registering async factory in Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854245/registering-async-factory-in-autofac)

Answer (score 2):

We ran into the same issue but found a different solution, I thought I'd share. You can wrap your async code within the Register method in a Task.Run and call `.GetResult()` or `.Wait()`. This will spawn a new context which ensures that any async code runs nicely within that context before being returned.

Sample taken from the other response snippet:

```
builder.Register(c =>
  {
      var bar= c.Resolve<IBar>();
      var foo = new Foo(bar);
      var resultTask = Task.Run(async () => {
           return await foo.ComputeAsync();
      });
      return resultTask.GetResult();
  })
.As<IFoo>()
.SingleInstance();
```

Comment: how is this different than https://stackoverflow.com/a/50451094/797369 ?

Comment: This worked for me, whereas Vetras' answer did not.